# Seleccionar un registro de un array en Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5, array

Hola quiero seleccionar un dato que está guardado en un array, por ejemplo el dato que necesito está en la posición 1, pero no sé cómo seleccionarlo:

Mi controlador es el siguiente, lo he minimizado para mayor comprensión:

```js
public function listaAlumnos()
    {
        $alumnos = DB::table('alumno')
        ->select('idalumno')
        ->get();

        $pr = $alumnos->idalumno[1]; //Necesito que el registro en la posición 1 se guarde en $pr.
    }
```

Si alguien me podría ayudar, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: `$alumnos`es un array? quizas basta con `$alumno[1]` ¿?

Answer (score 3):

Al utilizar get() estas recuperando un array de alumnos por lo tanto deberias utilizar un foreach():

```
$alumnos = DB::table('alumno')->select('idalumno')->get();
foreach($alumnos as $alumno){
  $pr = $alumnos->idalumno;
}
```

Si esperas recuperar solo un alumno puedes utilizar first():

```
$alumnos = DB::table('alumno')->select('idalumno')->first();
$pr = $alumnos->idalumno;
```

Comment: Creo que el nombre correcto del método es `first()` y no `firts()`, y otra pequeña precisión, el método `get()` no devuelve un array, devuelve una colección.